# R: creating new variable with conditions using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to create a new variable with dplyr.
My data looks like the following:

```
                Land     happy      year
               <fctr>    <int>     <dbl>
           1  Country1    09       2002
           2  Country1    08       2012
           3  Country3    05       2008
           ...
```

To create a variable with the mean of happy per Land and year, I used this code:

```
New <-df %>%
      group_by(Land, year) %>%
      mutate(mean.happy = mean(happy, na.rm=T))
```

Now I would like to make a variable with this content:
(mean of happy in 2012)- (mean of happy in 2008) for each Country.

How can I build a new variable with these conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dplyr/tidyr solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- df %>%
       group_by(Land, year) %>%
       mutate(mean.happy = mean(happy, na.rm=T)) %>%
       spread(year, mean.happy)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a data.table solution. It's typically faster

```
library(data.table)

dt = read.table("clipboard", header = TRUE)
setDT(dt)

dt[ , "mean.happy" := mean(happy), by = .(Land, year)]

dt[ , "diff.happiness" := mean(happy[year == 2012]) - mean(happy[year == 2008])]

> dt
       Land happy year mean.happy diff.happiness
1: Country1     9 2002          9              3
2: Country1     8 2012          8              3
3: Country3     5 2008          5              3
```